# Subprocess with visual studio debugger attached to process causes a problem in python project

Tags: python, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging, debugpy

I'm facing a very annoying issue with Visual Studio 2022. Here's how to replicate it.

Folder contents:

```
test-debugpy-issue
|   test-debugpy-issue.sln
|   
\---test-debugpy-issue
        cli.py
        test-debugpy-issue.pyproj
        test_debugpy_issue_simplified.py
```

Contents of `cli.py`:

```
print("hello world")
```

Contents of `test_debugpy_issue_simplified`:

```
import subprocess
import os
import json

print(os.getpid())
input()

configArgs = ["python", "cli.py"]

ret_code=0
while ret_code==0:
    ret_code = subprocess.call(configArgs, shell=False, universal_newlines=True)
    print(ret_code)
```

In order to replicate the issue, carry out the following steps:

- Open up a Powershell or CMD terminal
- Run `python .\test_debugpy_issue_simplified.py`
- Copy the provided PID
- In Visual Studio 2022 under *Debug > Attach to Process*, paste the PID, select the process as shown below:

[image]

- Click *Attach*, then wait in the *Output* window until the process has successfully attached. This apparently requires multiple attempts:

[image]

- Go back into your Powershell and CMD terminal and press *Enter*
- The following error should appear:

> 0.47s - Error importing debugpy._vendored.force_pydevd (with sys.path entry: 'c:\program > files\microsoft visual studio\2022\professional\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core')
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\professional\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy_vendored\pyde> vd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_defaults.py", line 60, in on_pydb_init
> **import**(module_name)
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debugpy'

I've found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/1148) issue on Github which describes a similar problem, but it's from the Vs Code repo. I'm not using VS Code.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it ?

Comment: The effect of my test here is that after running the python program, the process is successfully attached at once, and when I try to attach again later, the program and the button are grayed out. The python program did not report an error.

Comment: Professional, but I don't think that matters now. You mind deleting some of your earlier comments? The discussion is becoming needlessly long.

Comment: You can try to reinstall the python components and what about global install the debugpy? :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT no offense, but that's almost as bad as "Did you try restarting your computer?"

Answer (score 0):

I followed your steps and replicate the issue on my side.
I installed the package `debugpy` and tried to attach the process with debugger again, i found the error message disappeared and it entered debug mode.
You can use this command to check if there's available `debugpy` in your machine:

```
pip show debugpy
```

[image]

install debugpy:

```
 pip install debugpy
```